# How to Generate list of python with string element followed by numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to generate a python list similar to this:

```
['888_tir01','888_tir02','888_tir03','888_tir04'.........]
```

my question is how to generate such list?
I have thinking to create a list like this

```
['888_tir0']*100
```

and then concatinate the numbers with each element but don't know the easy way.
I appreciate any suggestions.
thanks!
Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str.format`:

```
out = ['888_tir{:02d}'.format(i) for i in range(1, 100)]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
['888_tir01', '888_tir02', '888_tir03', ...
```

Comment: Thanks! for a quick response